# Links disappear when window's width gets smaller bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

So I have a website and when I shrink the page the links disappear on the top. I am using bootstrap. You can find the website on Heroku here: https://rewardsapptest.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a bootstrap template that is designed to collapse the navbar for a mobile viewport. At that view, the navbar is toggable via a navbar-toggle button.

You need to;
A) include that button. Or,
B) Alternatively if you dont want to toggle the nav via a button, all you have ot do is remove the 'collapse' class from your 'navbar-collapse' div and re-style the links for mobile if you like.

Example A:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button><a class="navbar-brand" href="/joins/new">Yeti Rewards</a>
</div>
```

B:

```
<div id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse">
```

Comment: that worked, but when I click the "little sandwich," the links aren't showing up. Does it have something to do with the Javascript?

Comment: Update your site so I can see what's been changed.